# Make the image displaying side to side

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and was wondering how to make my images display side-by-side. I don't want to use `float:left`, but rather `display:inline-block`. I tried it but I couldn't get it to work.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WQdAY/) is the jsfiddle.

Comment: Please paste the HTML and CSS in the question as well, not only to jsfiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle references images that don't exist.  Is your problem that they're not appearing on the same line, or is it some other problem?

Comment: I want my images to be inline

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ttDgb/2/  Your problem is two fold:  1st, set the comment divs to inline-block.  2nd:  Why is your CommentBox Div of width: 0?  It's causing the images to line break.

Answer (score 4):

Your images are each inside of separate `<div>` tags. A `<div>` by default is going to look like `display: block`, and so what you need to do for your `comment1` and `comment2` classes is make *those* inline block. Additionally, because your `.MainBox .commentBox` is set to `width: 0px`, none of the elements below it are going to line up side by side. You'll need to remove that property if you want your images sitting next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use following CSS:

```
.MainBox {
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    width:1000px;
}  
.MainBox .commentBox {
    display:inline-block;
}
.MainBox .commentBox .comment1 {
    float:left;
}
.MainBox .commentBox .comment2 {
    float:left;          
}
```

Comment: But this uses `float: left`—Rodolfo asked for a solution that didn't utilize float.